# Problems loading scipy.stats.tukey_hsd in Spyder

Tags: scipy, spyder, scipy.stats

I have installed the package `scipy.stats` and now I want to use the `tukey_hsd` function in the [package](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.tukey_hsd.html). I get this error message once I try to load it

```
from scipy.stats import tukey_hsd

ImportError: cannot import name 'tukey_hsd' from 'scipy.stats' (C:\Users\2222\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py)
```

and this if I try through the imported stats package

```
from scipy import stats
tukey = stats.tukey_hsd(x,msx,m,ms,s)

AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'tukey_hsd'
```

Why is the specific function not available for me in the 'normal' stats package in Spyder?

Comment: `tukey_hsd` was added in SciPy version [1.8.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.8.0.html).  Which version are you using?  If you don't know, you can check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Alright! Seems to be the case, thanks a lot. I use 1.6.2 only.

Answer (score 1):

Tukey's HSD was introduced into scipy from version 1.8.0  and above. You need to check your version, and it is lower than 1.8.0, you have to upgrade your package.

With this you can check the scipy's version.

```
pip list | grep scipy
```

Then try to upgrade it to a version higher than 1.8.0

If you only need Tukey's HSD, I would recommend you use this command below to get 1.8.0

```
pip install scipy==1.8.0 --force
```

This will solve your problem.